# PrepareItemCraftEvent Issue - Could not pass event PrepareItemCraftEvent

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Does anyone have an idea why this event doesn't work?

OnEnable Code:

```
Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
```

Event Code:

```
@EventHandler(priority=EventPriority.HIGH)
public void customCrafting(PrepareItemCraftEvent e){    
    ItemStack singleCompressed = new ItemStack(Material.COBBLESTONE, 1);
    ItemStack nineCobblestone = new ItemStack(Material.COBBLESTONE, 9);
    ItemMeta singleCompressedMeta = singleCompressed.getItemMeta();
    singleCompressedMeta.setDisplayName("Compressed Cobblestone");
    singleCompressedMeta.setLore(Arrays.asList("x9 Cobblestone"));
    singleCompressed.setItemMeta(singleCompressedMeta);

    if(e.getInventory() instanceof CraftingInventory){
        CraftingInventory inv = (CraftingInventory) e.getInventory();
        ItemStack[] itm = inv.getMatrix();
        boolean canCraft = false;

        if (inv.getResult().getType() == Material.COBBLESTONE) {
            for (int i = 0; i < inv.getSize(); i++) {
                if(itm[i].getItemMeta().getLore().toString().toLowerCase().equals(singleCompressed.getItemMeta().getLore().toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    canCraft = true;
                }
            }
            if (canCraft == true) {
                inv.setResult(nineCobblestone);
                canCraft = false;   
            } else { 
                inv.setResult(null);
                canCraft = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have these recipes set up in a public void which is called by onEnable:

```
ShapedRecipe singleCompressedRecipe = new ShapedRecipe(singleCompressed);
    singleCompressedRecipe.shape("@@@","@@@","@@@");
    singleCompressedRecipe.setIngredient('@', Material.COBBLESTONE);

    ItemStack nineCobblestone = new ItemStack(Material.COBBLESTONE, 9);
    ShapelessRecipe decompressedRecipe = new ShapelessRecipe(nineCobblestone);
    decompressedRecipe.addIngredient(Material.COBBLESTONE);

    Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(singleCompressedRecipe);
    Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(decompressedRecipe);
```

For some reason whenever I try to craft accordingly, I get these errors in my console:

```
10:00:34 PM CONSOLE: ERROR]: Could not pass event PrepareItemCraftEvent to     CompressedBlocks v1.0
10:00:35 PM CONSOLE: Source) [?:1.7.0_60]
10:00:35 PM CONSOLE: Source) [?:1.7.0_60]
10:00:35 PM CONSOLE: Source) [?:1.7.0_60]
10:00:35 PM CONSOLE: Method) ~[?:1.7.0_60]
10:00:35 PM CONSOLE: Source) ~[?:1.7.0_60]
10:00:35 PM CONSOLE: Source) ~[?:1.7.0_60]
10:00:35 PM CONSOLE: Source) ~[?:1.7.0_60]
```

In terms of what happens in-game, you can craft 9 cobblestone from both regular and the single compressed cobblestone, so nothing is affected by the event. I have tried to log to the console: itm[i].getItemMeta().getLore().toString().toLowerCase() and it just equals null.

Comment: Could you include the entire error message? That could help a lot.

Comment: That is actually the entire error message that was given, 100%.

Comment: Thats really weird.  Are you using a plugin loader on your server by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is most likely throwing a NullPointerException because:

1. One of the slots in the crafting matrix is empty
2. One of the items in the matrix does not have lore text or metadata
3. The result slot of the crafting inventory is also empty

I would add null checks to make sure you're not working with a nonexistent item or metadata.

There are some other parts of your code that could be improved to make the compressed cobblestone work seamlessly.

The first problem you will run into is with the shaped recipe (the one that turns 9 cobblestones into a compressed item). Since the ingredients are defined using only the Material, a player can use 9 "compressed" cobblestones to craft another one, effectively removing 72 cobblestones. To fix this, whenever all 9 crafting slots are filled with cobblestone, we have to make sure that they are "simple" cobblestones (without metadata).

The second problem that I believe you were trying to fix with your code is the case in which a player turns a regular cobblestone instead of a compressed cobblestone into 9 cobblestones, effectively duping the blocks and giving the player an extra 8 cobblestones. This, as you probably already noticed, is once again because the ingredient of the shapeless recipe is only a Material and not an ItemStack. Below is some example code to fix both of these problems (tested, seemed to work pretty well):

```
public void onEnable() {
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);

    ItemStack result = new ItemStack(Material.COBBLESTONE, 1);
    ItemMeta meta = result.getItemMeta();
    meta.setDisplayName("Compressed Cobblestone");
    meta.setLore(Arrays.asList("9x Cobblestone"));
    result.setItemMeta(meta);

    //This recipe creates the problem that one can turn 9 compressed blocks into only one
    ShapedRecipe shaped = new ShapedRecipe(result);
    shaped.shape("@@@", "@@@", "@@@");
    shaped.setIngredient('@', Material.COBBLESTONE);

    //This recipe creates the problem that we can turn a regular cobblestone into 9
    ItemStack nine = new ItemStack(Material.COBBLESTONE, 9);
    ShapelessRecipe shapeless = new ShapelessRecipe(nine);
    shapeless.addIngredient(Material.COBBLESTONE);

    Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(shaped);
    Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(shapeless);
}

@EventHandler
public void onPrepareCraft(PrepareItemCraftEvent event) {
    ItemStack[] slots = event.getInventory().getMatrix();

    //The item list will only contain real itemstacks
    List<ItemStack> items = new ArrayList<ItemStack>();
    for (ItemStack slot : slots) {
        if (slot != null && slot.getType() != Material.AIR) { //We filter out air slots and null items
            items.add(slot);
        }
    }

    boolean canCraft = false;
    if (items.size() == 1) { //If we are dealing with a single item
        ItemStack item = items.get(0); //Get the first item
        if (item.getType() == Material.COBBLESTONE && item.hasItemMeta()) { //If this block is cobblestone and has metadata
            ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
            //Check if the metadata contains a display name and lore
            //If so, compare them with what they should be
            if (meta.hasDisplayName() && meta.hasLore() && meta.getDisplayName().equals("Compressed Cobblestone") && meta.getLore().toString().equals(Arrays.asList("9x Cobblestone").toString())) {
                canCraft = true;
            }
        }
    } else if (items.size() == 9) { //If we are dealing with 9 items
        boolean allCobblestone = true; //We need to check whether they are all cobblestone, otherwise we would interfere with other recipes that use all 9 slots
        for (ItemStack item : items) {
            if (item.getType() != Material.COBBLESTONE) {
                //If we find a non-cobblestone block, exit loop and let the player craft whatever he is trying to make
                allCobblestone = false;
                canCraft = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (allCobblestone) { //If we have 9 cobblestones in the matrix make sure none of them have metadata
            canCraft = true;
            for (ItemStack item : items) {
                if (item.hasItemMeta()) {
                    canCraft = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!canCraft) {
        event.getInventory().setResult(null);
    }
}
```